# What is the accepted string format for CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, versioning, info.plist

I'm looking at the official documentation for [CFBundleVersion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion) and [CFBundleShortVersionString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring), and the following is mentioned:

> The string can only contain numeric characters (0-9) and periods.

However, I was able to add virtually any string I like to the plist file locally and deploy the app to a physical device. Is it correct to say the above restriction will only be enforced during AppStore view?

But then, I saw some public apps that had alphabetic characters (e.g. https://apps.apple.com/mx/app/gasoapp/id1190356107 and click `Historial de actualizaciones`).

My question is, what is the accepted format for these keys?

Answer (score 0):

CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString get validated once you upload your app to App Store Connect. If they have an incorrect format, Apple will reject the build immediately and it won't be available for TestFlight or live deployment.

Both values are not visible to the end user in the first place. Testers can see it in TestFlight, but the value you are referring to is the version string you set in App Store Connect. That one is customer facing and can be any 64-bit string. Most developers simply "re-use" their CFBundleVersion, but there are also others how use more descriptive names like "2021 Spring Release", "2021.01.04" or similar.

For CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString I would recommend to follow Apple's examples of 1.0.0 and so on.